# Run a script in Python

Tags: shell, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm a beginner in `Python`. I'm trying to launch a few lines of code to understand how it works (Python 3.4). My doubts are about the different enviroments of the language: I have an editor in which I can write a script and run it, an environment called `shell`, where I can interact with the terminal and an environment with command line (console) .
I would like to understand what are the differences between these three enviroment, in particular:

- In `Editor` (`new file`) from the menu `run` I can choice `Python Shell` and `Run Module`, which is the difference between the two?
- What is the difference between the `shell` environment and the command line one? I noticed that if I launch from `shell` something like:

  if 2==2:

  print("ok")

this is executed correctly, but if I execute the same `if` statement directly from the command line, there is this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line2
print("ok")
IdentationError: expected an indented block
```

Beyond my doubts, I really appreciate if someone would explain me generally the difference between shell and command line, thanks.

Comment: In Python white space characters are part of syntax - so `IdentationError` is basically syntax error. Your if block should be denoted by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: I don't know what `shell` is, but if it doesn't raise an error for `if 2==2:\nprint("ok")` because there's no indentation, then it's not Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses the whitespace as a part of code,
Instead of using the c++ parentheses {} or other code block begin / end it uses it as a method of distinguishing the blocks of code

The example of different code for python:

1)

```
 if true:
    dosomething()
 dosomething()
```

2)

```
if true:
dosomething()
dosomething()
```

3)

```
  if true:
      dosomething()
      dosomething()
```

after if you are expected to have different intention block therefore the 2nd example is causing the issues (as it looks for python interpreter that your if has empty body)